# jQuery , changing value with live odds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

this is my 1st time posting here, so sorry if i'm not gonna be clear wiht my question from first shoot :). Ok, let me explain where i'm stuck. I got a portal where odds can be changed any second, that means, if u pick one odd now, it can be changed any second, so that means that u have to change your bet on that odd.

This site is best example of what i wanna get.
http://www1.betuniq.eu/it/live (pick some match so u can see odds for betting)

When i pick some odd, that odd get hovered with some css class, but when that same odd change it's value, hover disappears. What i wanna get is next. When that odd change its value i wanna another color of hover ?!

In short, thats my problem. I hope I wrote understandable.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with jQuery. It's something like this. This is not the most elegant way, maybe someone else can suggest you a littlebit more clear solution. Till that time, you can check this:

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.odd').click(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
                $(this).addClass('clicked');
                $(this).css('background-color', "#00f");
            }
        });

        $(".odd").hover(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
                $(this).css('background-color', "#f00");
            }
        }, function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
                $(this).css('background-color', "#fff");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    div.odd {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="odd">This is a text</div>
```